# count rows groupby column of dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Does anyone knwos how to count rows groupby column.
Example i have column **col1** of my dataframe **df** as shown in the example below.

I want to print (LA:2, NY: 3, PARIS:1, JAPAN:1)

```
d = {'col1': ['LA', 'LA', 'NY', 'PARIS', 'JAPAN', 'NY', 'NY']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

PLease help me,

Thank you,

Comment: Check second answer.

Comment: do you mean this **df.groupby(['col1']).size()** ?

Comment: exactly, or `df['col1'].value_counts()`